# Setting the minimum column width in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Greetings.

For the life of me, I can't remember how to set the minimum width on an SSRS column.  When I render the report in 'Preview' mode it looks fine, but when I set it up as a subscription to go out via email it gets scrunched together.

Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the ReportingServices.css file.  By default, it's found in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles\
```

Here's the CSS:

```
td, th
{
  min-width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for marking this late, and I appreciate the correct answer so quickly.